# UITableViewDiffableDataSource iPad issue

Tags: swift, ipad, uikit, uitableviewdiffabledatasource

I have a crash error message - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: itemIdentifier'

I used a UITableViewDiffableDataSource to implement my UITableView. And when I try to "dataSource?.apply" a have a crash. It happens only on iPad, iPhone works fine

Do you know what is a reason and How to solve it?

Code example

```
class myVC: UIViewController {

    struct Section: Hashable {
        enum Kind: Hashable, CaseIterable {
            case `default`
            case full
        }
        
        let title: String? = nil
        let kind: Kind
        let items: [Item]
    }

    struct Item: Hashable {
        let title: String?
        let detailTitle: String?
        let subDetailTitle: String?
        let image: UIImage?
        let isActionable: Bool
        let action: ((Any?) -> Void)?
    }
    private typealias DataSource = UITableViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>
    private typealias Snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Item>
    
    private var dataSource: DataSource?

    private var flag: Bool = false

    func setData(sections: [TimeLogDetailViewController.Section]) {
        var snapshot = Snapshot()
    
        
        sections.forEach { section in
            snapshot.appendSections([section])
            snapshot.appendItems(section.items, toSection: section)
        }
        
        dataSource?.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
    }


   func configureSections() -> [TimeLogDetailViewController.Section] {
        var sections = [TimeLogDetailViewController.Section]()
        
        if !flag {
            sections.append(configFirstSection())
        } else {
            sections.append(emptySection(kind: .default))
            sections.append(configSecondSection())
        }
        return sections
    }
    
    func emptySection(kind: TimeLogDetailViewController.Section.Kind) -> TimeLogDetailViewController.Section {
        Section(kind: kind, items: [])
    }

    func configFirstSection() -> [Item] {
        [Item(title: "Title"))]
    }
    
    func configHeaderSectionItems() -> [Item] {
        return configFirstSection().append([Item(title: "SecondTitle")])
    }


}
```

Comment: What does "And when I try to change a section a have a crash" mean?

Comment: I have a flag. When flag changed, I want to remake first section "empty" and add second section with my current items.

Comment: @ElTomato, Sorry, I corrected description

Comment: Did you find what's the problem?